# AnormCypher: How to get a complete path for a given node?

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher, anormcypher

For a graph consisting of two groups of nodes:

n1 -> n2 -> n3 -> n4

and

n5 -> n6 -> n7

Created with commands:

CREATE (n1 { id:'n1' })-[:rel]->(n2 {id:'n2' })-[:rel]->(n3 { id:'n3' })-[:rel]->(n4 {id:'n4'})

CREATE (n5 { id:'n5' })-[:rel]->(n6 {id:'n6' })-[:rel]->(n7 { id:'n7' })

For both requests:

MATCH p = (n {id: 'n1'})-[*]-(m) RETURN nodes(p) as nodes;

MATCH p = (n {id: 'n1'})-[*]-(m) RETURN relationships(p) as rels ;

AnormCypher (http://anormcypher.org/) returns info related only to nodes n1 and n2, while Neo4J Web console returns a complete path.

How to get *all* nodes and relations for the complete path in AnormCypher?

Program that demonstrates this (at the end of this message) outputs:

```
ListBuffer(NeoNode(32,Map(id -> n1)), NeoNode(33,Map(id -> n2)))
Node: id=32 props=Map(id -> n1)
--Props keys:
----key: id val: n1
Node: id=33 props=Map(id -> n2)
--Props keys:
----key: id val: n2
ListBuffer(NeoRelationship(27,Map(),32,33))
Rel: id=27 start=32 end=33 props=Map()
```

Code:

```
object Simple {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

Cypher("MATCH p = (n {id: 'n1'})-[*]-(m) RETURN nodes(p) as nodes;")().map { row =>

  println(row[Seq[org.anormcypher.NeoNode]]("nodes"))
  val nodes = row[Seq[org.anormcypher.NeoNode]]("nodes")

  nodes.map(n => {
    val props = n.props
    println("Node: id="+n.id+" props="+props)
    println("--Props keys: ")
    val x = props.keys
    props.keys.map( k=> println("----key: "+k+" val: "+props(k)))
    })
}

Cypher("MATCH p = (n {id: 'n1'})-[*]-(m) RETURN relationships(p) as rels ;")().map { row =>

  println(row[Seq[NeoRelationship]]("rels"))
  val rels = row[Seq[NeoRelationship]]("rels")
  rels.map(r => {
    val x = r.props
    println("Rel: id="+r.id+" start="+r.start+" end="+r.end+" props="+r.props)
  })
}

 }
}
```

Comment: Is this the right forum to ask this? Have you tried adding an issue to the AnormCypher open source repo? https://github.com/AnormCypher/AnormCypher/issues

Comment: @cybersam seems reasonable to ask it here--it's not really a bug, per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `map` function is creating a lazy stream, and you're not iterating over the rest of the stream. If you add `.toList` or `.last` to the end of your `.map`, forcing the iteration over the full stream, you should get the longer path results.

For example:

```
Cypher("MATCH p = (n {id: 'n1'})-[*]-(m) RETURN nodes(p) as nodes;")().map { row =>
  println(row[Seq[org.anormcypher.NeoNode]]("nodes"))
  val nodes = row[Seq[org.anormcypher.NeoNode]]("nodes")

  nodes.map(n => {
    val props = n.props
    println("Node: id="+n.id+" props="+props)
    println("--Props keys: ")
    val x = props.keys
    props.keys.map( k=> println("----key: "+k+" val: "+props(k)))
    })
}.toList
```

Alternatively, you could just use `.foreach` instead of `.map`, which does this for you.

Update: Here's an example that has no return type:

```
Cypher("MATCH p = (n {id: 'n1'})-[*]-(m) RETURN nodes(p) as nodes;")().foreach { row =>
  println(row[Seq[org.anormcypher.NeoNode]]("nodes"))
  val nodes = row[Seq[org.anormcypher.NeoNode]]("nodes")

  nodes.map(n => {
    val props = n.props
    println("Node: id="+n.id+" props="+props)
    println("--Props keys: ")
    val x = props.keys
    props.keys.map( k=> println("----key: "+k+" val: "+props(k)))
    })
}
```

Comment: In your answer above you apply `toList` function to anonymous function `(n => {...})` that just produce side-effect with `println` and has a return type of collection of `Unit` elements. So it looks like this code tries to build some list of `Units`, is it correct?

Comment: If you really just want to print them out, use foreach instead of map, added an example in case my intention wasn't clear.

Comment: And no, `toList` is being applied to the `Stream` that is the result of the `map`, not the function.